# WaitPoint and Event

Tags: autosar

I have been reading about developing an Autosar Software Component. I'm still confuse about `WaitPoint` and `Event` on internal behavior. What are the main differences between `WaitPoint` and `Event` in AUTOSAR Software Component? and it will be great if you can show me a sample of c code according to them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `Event` in AUTOSAR has two different meanings regarding software components. Either it triggers a `RunnableEntity` or it resolves a `WaitPoint`. If a `RunnableEntity` is triggered e.g. by a `DataReceivedEvent` the Rte will activate your `RunnableEntity` and then you can call Rte_Read() to read the data. The second case is when you define a `WaitPoint` for that `RunnableEntity` and let the `DataReceivedEvent` resolve it. If you then call Rte_Receive() the function will block until new data is received.

Usually, such a function is implemented by an OSEK `WaitEvent()` and if the Rte receives data, it will use the OSEK `SetEvent` function to wakeup the task that called `WaitEvent()`.

Comment: ① So, `Rte_Receive()` is always paired with `WaitPoint`? 
② What happened when I call `Rte_Receive` or `Rte_Read` without define `WaitPoint` or `Event` on the RunnableEntity?

Comment: You can have a blocking or a non-blocking `Rte_Receive()`. If you have no `WaitPoint` it's always non-blocking. With `Rte_Read` only non-blocking is possible. You can configure a `Rte_Read` or `Rte_Receive` even without a `DataReceivedEvent`.